# What exactly is an environment variable in Node/Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, environment-variables, server

I know this is a relatively simple question, but I do not see this being asked. In Node/Express, I always set this :

```
var port = PROCESS.env.PORT || 9000
```

and I know that PROCESS.env.PORT is my environment variable. However, I don't know *what* an environment variable is, and how it pertains to development and production, and why/how it is needed and used in the many circumstances that it appears in any given repository.

Comment: environment variables are ones that were provided by the OS when the process was started.

Comment: Environment variables are shell variables, e.g., `export PORT=3000`. They store arbitrary information. Asking Google "what is an environment variable" is probably a good place to start, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable

Comment: An environment variable is not a Node.js concept; it is a general computing concept, and `process.env` happens to be how to access environment vars in Node.js. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env

Answer (score 3):

To add to what others said in the comments, one way to set these variables is as you launch your node.js program, for example:

`PORT=9100 node server.js`

Another way it to set the variable first and make it available (with EXPORT) as Dave Newton indicated:

```
export PORT=9100
node server.js
```

Comment: if we are the one who will set environment variable in node.js then what is the point of use of  '''var port = PROCESS.env.PORT || 9000'''? I mean then we can directly use  ''server.listen(3000); "

Comment: @Shwetapatel it's common to use an environment variable so that you can use one value in development and another in production, for example, run your site on port 3000 in development but on port 80 in production. By using an environment variable you can deploy the same code and configure it to do different things via environment variables.